# Android - align textViews issue

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-xml

I am developing an android application. And I have a lot of TextViews in the same line. 
But when the TextView became larger, it goes to a new line but not aligned to the left.

This is what I need:

[image]

This is what I have now:

[image]

My code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_right" />

 <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/due_after"
     android:textColor="@color/black" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv_due_days"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
     android:text=" 500 days"
     android:textColor="@color/red" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv_redemption"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/from_earn_date"
     android:textColor="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Single textview to show data and if you want texts to be of different colors use SpannableStringBuilder.

Example :

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

String red = "this is red";
SpannableString redSpannable= new SpannableString(red);
redSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, red.length(), 0);
builder.append(redSpannable);

String white = "this is white";
SpannableString whiteSpannable= new SpannableString(white);
whiteSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, white.length(), 0);
builder.append(whiteSpannable);

String blue = "this is blue";
SpannableString blueSpannable = new SpannableString(blue);
blueSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, blue.length(), 0);
builder.append(blueSpannable);

mTextView.setText(builder, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having three textviews make it as single textview and use spannable string in order to make 500day as red color

Example :

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

String str = "Due date after 500day from earned points date";
SpannableString mutableStr= new SpannableString(str);
redSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 15, 21, 0);
builder.append(mutableStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you are using two separate text views when you can use a single text view.

You can concatenate the "500 days" into the original text view.

```
firstTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.STRING_NAME, 500));
```

As long as you have the string in your Res>Values>String.xml file.

```
<string name="STRING_NAME">Due date after %1$f from earned points date</string>
```